# Scalar error when swapping out a hard coded string for a variable with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**df1** looks something like this:

```
  name  age
1 Bobby 17
2 Sally 23
3 John  19
```

**df2** looks like this:

```
  name  city      state
1 Bobby Lakeside  MN
2 Sally Carlstown MS
3 John  Wallsburg UT
```

I am looping through a DataFrame, df1, like this:

```
for row in df1.itertuples(name='Pandas', index=True):
    name = getattr(row, "name")
    print(type(name))
    print(name)
```

and I will get (as expected):

```
<type 'str'>
Bobby
<type 'str'>
Sally
<type 'str'>
John
```

Then I am searching a second dataframe, df2, and getting it's row location (index) number, so I can get additional information.

```
i = df2[(df2['name'] == "Bobby").index.item()
```

`i` is now the integer... worked like a champ. It found Bobby in the other DataFrame, df2, and walla! Gave me the index number.

**However...** if I try swapping out the hard coded string "Bobby" to the variable like this...

```
for row in df1.itertuples(name='Pandas', index=True):
    name = getattr(row, "name")
    i = df2[(df2['name'] == name)].index.item()
```

then it explodes and dies.

```
for row in df1.itertuples(name='Pandas', index=True):
    name = getattr(row, "name")
    i = df2[(df2['name'] == str(name))].index.item()
```

I get the following exception:

```
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

I am at a complete loss, help! and Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using `getattr` here at all? Both of your later examples are syntactically incorrect btw, they're missing a `]`

Comment: I want to get the values from that specific column/row. (I'm sure there's a better way to do this) ... but I am going to be playing with the values for later down the road. I am also ultra new to Pandas.

Comment: If you don't mind, what exactly are you trying to do?  If you are using for loops with Pandas, then you are not taking full advantage of the library.  What is your desired output?

Comment: Oh thank @youroganjosh, fixed it.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do though.`getattr` is not a pandas method, so it's unclear to me what value`name` should be taking in your example. Can you please give a small example of input and expected output?

Comment: @Scott Boston eventually I would like to do things such as (not limited to) combining them like this...

`z = df2.at[i, 'State']`

`example = "{0} who is {1} lives in {2}".format(name,age,z)`

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems overcomplicated. You can create a name to age mapping from `df1` and iterate `df2.iterrows`. There is no need to access indices, unless you have repeated names. In the latter case, you can use the index.

```
s = df1.set_index('name')['age']

for _, row in df2.iterrows():
    print('{0} who is {1} lives in {2}'.format(row['name'], s.get(row['name']), row.city))

Bobby who is 17 lives in Lakeside
Sally who is 23 lives in Carlstown
John who is 19 lives in Wallsburg
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I follow, but not entirely sure.

I still haven't figured out why it breaks if I use a string variable, but doesn't if I hard code the string. I tried using your sample above, but I am sure I am doing something wrong, as it isn't working.

Comment: @Jeff, That's strange, I copied *your* `df1` and `df2`. So maybe there's some other strange aspect of your dataframe we haven't been able to identify.